# es6 destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm looping over an object to create number of arrays inside dataSet.

```
 dataSet = []
     this.props.users.map((item) => {
      dataSet.push([item.profile.firstName, item.profile.lastName])
     })
```

How can I apply es6 destructuring? here is what I have tried, but keep getting syntax error.

```
     dataSet = []
     this.props.users.map((item) => {
      let {firstName, lastName } = item.profile
      dataSet.push([firstName, lastName])
     })
```

Comment: Are you sure that the JavaScript environment you're testing in supports ES2015 destructuring assignment?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using latest version of React.js

Comment: Ummm... React.js is not an environment. Also maybe show/telling us the actual syntax error would be helpful?

Comment: I think the problem is caused by missing semicolons.

Comment: @torazaburo Why? There's nothing ambiguous here and it transpiles fine.

Comment: Perhaps actually including the error you get would be useful. There's no syntax error if you're in an environment that supports ES6: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=%20%20%20%20%20dataSet%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20this.props.users.map((item)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20%7BfirstName%2C%20lastName%20%7D%20%3D%20item.profile%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20dataSet.push(%5BfirstName%2C%20lastName%5D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A

Comment: By "JavaScript environment" I mean the browser you're using, or Node, or whatever.

Comment: @torazaburo Why what you said?

Comment: @DaveNewton It was a joke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're creating extra work for yourself by performing push inside of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control). Map will return an array for you naturally. Try this snippet out:

```js
let props = {
  users: [
    {
      profile: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        sex: "male"
      }
    },
    {
      profile: {
        firstName: "Jane",
        lastName: "Doe",
        sex: "female"
      }
    }
  ]
};

const newArr = props.users.map(({profile: {firstName, lastName}}) => [firstName, lastName]);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Or `const newArr = props.users.map(({ profile }) => [ profile.firstName, profile.lastName ])` I don't always use parameter destructuring, but when it makes simple property grabs like this so tight IMO it's worth it.

Comment: In any case, this doesn't address the actual question.

Comment: The question was "How can I apply es6 destructuring?". This does show that. I agree though, there's no real need to deconstruct in this situation, but it's contrived as an example.

Comment: You duplicated the destructuring--that doesn't help since the code isn't the issue. It's good to point out how to use `map` correctly, but it might be nice to address the underlying issue instead of echoing the code with the problem back verbatim.

Comment: @Dave Newton that was a sample code, actually my database has over 22 fields.

Comment: @Deano Neat. I'd still destructure instead of typing the same words over and over again, but YMMV.

Comment: I'm confused that you did not propose `const newArr = props.users.map(({profile: {firstName, lastName}}) => [firstName, lastName]);`.

Comment: @torazaburo that line of code still does not work. `firstName` & `lastName` are contained within each users profile.

Comment: It should work now. Anyway, I assume you get the idea, which is to destructure in the parameter list.

Comment: Yes sir, it works now and I have amended my answer to provide your solution. I learned something here. I did not realize you could destructure in the arguments of the callback. Thank you.